# jQuery onclick only works on second click

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a simple onclick function in jQuery, however it only fires on the second click and there after?

I've tried the following:

```
$('.element').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
});

$('body').on('click', '.element', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
});
```

Any ideas as to why this would be happening?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine from the first click: https://jsfiddle.net/8j151t8a/. Could you provide a working example of the problem using a snippet in your question.

Comment: Can you update your question with some HTML of `$('.element')`. It could be the way your dom is loaded. Best!

Comment: e.preventDefault(); is the preblem you are preventing the alert 
its a "BOM" Browser Object model thing try to remove it 
any BOM element dose not work will with e.preventDefault(); like alerts for example

Answer (score 0):

Your script isn't waiting for the document to load.Place your script inside document ready function hopefully it will work.

> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> //your code
>
> });

Comment: Yeah my code is within this but for some reason only works on second click?